# wifi access point?

Tags: wireless, hot-spot

Can I create wifi access point from ubuntu desktop 12.10 so as to connect my mobile it won't support ad-hoc network? On windows it was done by connectify but I recently switched to ubuntu and I dont know how to create it? I am using lan for internet.

Comment: I had the same problem and I've not found a solution yet. I can only patiently wait for Android to support ad-hoc.